# DataTables warning: table id={id} - Requested unknown parameter {paramater} for row 0, column 0. - JSON and AJAX Error

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables

I have read the datatables.net documentation on populating a datatable using ajax and can't get anywhere.

FROM THE CONTROLLER USING ASP.NET Core, the following method:

```
[HttpGet ("EmployeesJSON")]
public JsonResult EmployeesJSON()
{
   var AllEmployees = _iEmployeeService.GetAllEmployees();
   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AllEmployees, Formatting.Indented);
   return new JsonResult(json);
}
```

Result returned from controller:
[image]

FROM Javascript using AJAX

```
var _data;
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('GET'),
            url: "Employees/EmployeesJSON", 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) { // on success..            
                _data = response;
                initDataTable(); //initialize the data table
            }
        }); 
    });
```

What data looks like from AJAX call
[image]

initDataTable() is called if success from AJAX Call

```
function initDataTable() {
       var employeeTable = $('#employee_table').DataTable(
        {
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: 400,
            data: _data, 
            columns: [
                { sName: "LastName", data: "LastName", bSearchable: true, bSortable: false }
            ],
            lengthMenu: [[25, 50, -1], [25, 50, 'All']],            
        });
}
```

Error message from datatables.net

[image: Error message from datatables.net]

Comment: I recommend using the built-in support for Ajax provided by DataTables, instead of a separate jQuery Ajax call. You can see examples, including this one: [Custom data source property](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html). In your case, it appears as if the JSON array you receive has no name - and therefore you would need to use `dataSrc: ''` instead of the example's `dataSrc: 'demo'`. Your data is also an array of objects (not an array of arrays) so you need to map the object values as shown in [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm placing this here in case someone else runs into this.

I was referencing a column with the wrong field name.  Make sure your column names match!
Final AJAX and datatable init:

```
 (document).ready(function () {
        var editLink = '<a class="editLink"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg" style="font-size:.8em;color:green;"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span></a>';
        var employee_table = $('#employee_table').DataTable({
            //scroll x and y are required to keep make the header scroll on horizontal
            scrollY: 600,
            scrollX: true,
            ajax: {
                url: 'Employees/EmployeesJSON',
                dataSrc: '',
            },
            columns: [
                { data: null, defaultContent: editLink, sortable: false },
                { data: "EmployeeName", searchable: true, sortable: true },
                { data: "ForemanName", searchable: true, sortable: true },
                { data: "SeniorityCode", searchable: true, sortable: true, className: 'text-center' },
                { data: "JobCode", searchable: true, sortable: true },
                { data: "DateAssigned", searchable: true, sortable: true },
                { data: "OvertimeGroupDescription", searchable: true, sortable: true },
                { data: "ScheduleGroup", searchable: false, sortable: true, className: 'text-center' },
                { data: "AdjustedHours", searchable: false, sortable: true, className: 'text-center' },
                { data: "OvertimeRefusal", searchable: false, sortable: true, className: 'text-center' },
                { data: "DateHired", searchable: false, sortable: true },
                { data: "DateTerminated", searchable: true, sortable: true }
            ],
            order: [ [11, 'asc'],[1, 'asc']],
            "fnDrawCallback": function () {
                $('table#employee_table td').bind('mouseenter', function () { $(this).parent().children().each(function () { $(this).addClass('datatablerowhighlight'); }); });
                $('table#employee_table td').bind('mouseleave', function () { $(this).parent().children().each(function () { $(this).removeClass('datatablerowhighlight'); }); });
            },
            lengthMenu: [[25, 50, -1], [25, 50, 'All']],  
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api()
                    .columns()
                    .every(function () {
                        var column = this;
                        //add drop downs only to foreman, overtime group
                        if (column.index() == 2 || column.index() == 6) {
                            var select = $('<br/><select><option value=""></option></select>')
                                .appendTo($(column.header()))
                                .on('change', function () {
                                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                                    column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
                                });
                            column
                                .data()
                                .unique()
                                .sort()
                                .each(function (d, j) {
                                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                                });
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
        //edit individual record event
        $('#employee_table tbody').on('click', '.editLink', function () {
            var data = employee_table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            document.location.href = 'Employees/' + data['PN'];
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the names in quotes

```
columns: [
          {"title": "LastName", "data": "LastName", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": false }
         ],
```

if you still have some problems, you can try a camel case

```
  ... "data": "lastName",...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo using the suggestions I made in my comments:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    </table>

</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY: 400,
    ajax: {
      url: 'Employees/EmployeesJSON',
      dataSrc: '',
    },
    columns: [
      { 
        title: "Last Name",
        name: "LastName",
        data: "LastName", 
        searchable: true, 
        sortable: false 
      },
      { 
        title: "First Name",
        name: "FirstName",
        data: "FirstName", 
        searchable: true, 
        sortable: false 
      } //,
      // add more columns here...
    ],
    lengthMenu: [[25, 50, -1], [25, 50, 'All']]
  } );

} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It assumes your Ajax call returns JSON like the following:

```
[
  {
    "PN": "149458",
    "FirstName": "MICHAEL",
    "LastName": "ADAMS",
    "DateHired": "2016-02-01",
    "DateTerminated": null
  },
  {
     //... another row of data here
  },
  ...
]
```

Notes:

1. My sample JSON only contains 5 fields per record - your JSON contains more, of course.
2. My DataTable only uses 2 of my 5 fields - but you can extend my code to add more fields, as needed. See the `columns:` section of the code.
3. I have used the DataTables built-in support for Ajax (it makes the code simpler, in my opinion, but you can still use an external Ajax call if you prefer).
4. Because your JSON uses an unnamed array (according to the screenshot in your question), you need to use `dataSrc: ''`. This tells DataTables where the array can be found in your JSON.

In contrast, if you had JSON that looked like this (just as an example):

```
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "PN": "149458",
      "FirstName": "MICHAEL",
      "LastName": "ADAMS",
      "DateHired": "2016-02-01",
      "DateTerminated": null
    },
    {
       //... another row of data here
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

...then you would need to use `dataSrc: 'foo'` because that is where the array of objects is located in the JSON

5. Instead of using variables such as `sName` and `bSearchable`, I use the modern versions `name`, `searchable` and so on. The older names still work.